# Argument of groupBy's Lambda

Tags: haskell

[Learn You a Haskell](http://learnyouahaskell.com/modules#loading-modules) shows the `groupBy` function:

```
ghci> let values = [-4.3, -2.4, -1.2, 0.4, 2.3, 5.9, 10.5, 
                          29.1, 5.3, -2.4, -14.5, 2.9, 2.3]  
ghci> groupBy (\x y -> (x > 0) == (y > 0)) values  
[[-4.3,-2.4,-1.2],[0.4,2.3,5.9,10.5,29.1,5.3],[-2.4,-14.5],[2.9,2.3]]
```

In `groupBy`'s first argument, what is the meaning of the lambda's 2 arguments: `x` and `y`?

Comment: Are you asking what this expression does, or why there are two arguments in the lambda?

Comment: Could you please tell me both?

Comment: With the function `on` from `Data.Function` you could write `ghci> groupBy ((==) \`on\` (>0)) values` . Maybe its more readable for you.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Haskell: surprising behavior of "groupBy"](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1316365/haskell-surprising-behavior-of-groupby)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

These are the variables to compare. You know that `group` puts equal neighbored values together. To decide what a equal value is it uses a compare function. `group` relies on the instance of your type of the `Eq` typeclass. But `groupBy` allows you to choose how to compare the neighbored values.

Answer (score 1):

If we look at the type of `groupBy`:

```
groupBy :: (a -> a -> Bool) -> [a] -> [[a]]
```

The first argument to `groupBy` is a function that takes two arguments of type `a` and return a `Bool`.  You could equivalently write this as

```
groupBy comparer values where comparer x y = (x > 0) == (y > 0)
```

The `\x y ->` part just says that the lambda function takes two arguments named `x` and `y`, just like with any other function declaration.

The easiest way to see what this expression does is to just run it:

```
ghci> groupBy (\x y -> (x > 0) == (y > 0)) values
[[-4.3,-2.4,-1.2],[0.4,2.3,5.9,10.5,29.1,5.3],[-2.4,-14.5],[2.9,2.3]]
```

If you look closely, you can see that each sublist is grouped by if it's positive or negative.  The `groupBy` function groups elements of a list by the given condition, but only in sequential order.  For example:

```
ghci> groupBy (\x y -> x == y) [1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 4]
[[1,1],[2,2,2],[3,3],[4]]
ghci> groupBy (\x y -> x == y) [1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 1]
[[1,1],[2,2,2],[3,3],[1]]
```

In the second example, notice that the `1`s haven't all been grouped together because they aren't adjacent.

Comment: This was helpful, especially the last part where you implemented `group` in terms of `groupBy`.

Answer (score 1):

In cases like these, it's best to go straight to the source! `groupBy` is part of `Data.List`, so you can find it the `base` package on [Hackage](http://hackage.haskell.org/). When you don't know what package a function is in, search for the function in [Hoogle](http://www.haskell.org/hoogle/) and click on the name to be taken to the Haddocks on Hackage. When you're looking at Haddock documentation, there will usually be a "Source" link on the righthand side of the function type definition to take you to the definition. Here's the source for [`groupBy`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.7.0.0/docs/src/Data-List.html#groupBy).

I've reproduced the definition here to step through it.

```
-- | The 'groupBy' function is the non-overloaded version of 'group'.
groupBy                 :: (a -> a -> Bool) -> [a] -> [[a]]
groupBy _  []           =  []
groupBy eq (x:xs)       =  (x:ys) : groupBy eq zs
                           where (ys,zs) = span (eq x) xs
```

First, the documentation line at the top tells us that `groupBy` is the non-overloaded version of `group`, which is a very common pattern in `base`. You can go check out `group` to figure out the simplest case of grouping functionality, then you can understand the -`By` version as allowing you to supply your own predicate (in case you wanted to compare equality differently than the `Eq` instance for a type, or whatever other operation you're trying to do).

The base case is trivial, but the recursive step might be a little confusing if you don't know what `span` does (time to hit Hackage again!). `span` takes a predicate and a list and returns a pair (2-tuple) of lists broken before the first element that doesn't match the predicate (it's like `break` but (not) negated).

So now you should be able to put it all together and see that `groupBy` groups elements of a list together by segregating runs of elements which are "equal" to the first element in that run. Note that it is NOT comparing elements pairwise (I was burned by that before) so don't assume that the two elements being passed to the predicate function would be adjacent in the list!

Comment: When you say `it is NOT comparing elements pairwise`, that means elements are **in fact** getting compared in an interleaving fashion, rather than paired up?

Comment: Hm, I'm not sure what you mean by "interleaving". What I meant is that it isn't comparing neighboring elements, it is instead consuming elements that evaluate to true while compared with the first element of the span. E.g., given a predicate like `(<)` and a list like `[1,2,4,3,0,...]` `groupBy` will compare and match `1 < 2`, `1 < 4`, `1 < 3` and then fail on `1 < 0` and begin a new group at the `0` element. This is instead of comparing `1 < 2`, `2 < 4`, `4 < 3`, &c. I expected the latter functionality early in using Haskell and got burned. A good exercise is to implement `pairwiseGroupBy`.

Answer (score 0):

Let's start with `group`. This function simply groups together all the adjacent elements that are identical. e.g.,

```
group [0,1,2,3,3,4] = [[0],[1],[2],[3,3],[4]]
```

GHC defines `group` as follows:

```
group :: Eq a => [a] -> [[a]]
group =  groupBy (==)
```

That is, the equality test is implicit. The same thing can be written with an explicit equality test using `groupBy` as;

```
groupBy (\x y -> x == y) [0,1,2,3,3,4] = [[0],[1],[2],[3,3],[4]]
```

Now, let's look at how GHC defines `groupBy`:

```
groupBy :: (a -> a -> Bool) -> [a] -> [[a]]
groupBy _  []           =  []
groupBy eq (x:xs)       =  (x:ys) : groupBy eq zs
                           where (ys,zs) = span (eq x) xs
```

`eq` is used to split the rest of the list based on comparison with the first element. `groupBy` is then recursively called on the list of elements that fail the comparison. Note that `(x:ys)` is a concatenation of the first element, with the list of elements that satisfy the comparison condition. Also, the `span` function will start the second list at the first element where test condition is not met.

Hence, in the given example, the moment you reach the value 0.4, a new list has to start, since 0.4 will be the first element of `zs` from the above definition.

Answer (score 0):

[`groupBy`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.7.0.2/docs/Data-List.html#v:groupBy) divides a list into groups according to some “rule”. In `` groupBy (\x y -> x `someComparison` y) someList ``, `x` is a first element of the “current” group, `y` is an element of `someList`. `groupBy` traverses `someList`, so at each step `y` becomes the next element of `someList`. The new group started, when the predicate returns `False`. `y` becomes the first member of the new group. Iteration continues, the first member of this new group now becomes `x`, and the next element of `someList` becomes `y`.

`groupBy` does **NOT** compare elements pairwise (1<sup>st</sup> with 2<sup>nd</sup>, 2<sup>nd</sup> with 3<sup>rd</sup>, etc), instead it compares each element of the list with the **first** element of the group currently being filled. Example:

```
groupBy (\x y -> x < y) [1,2,3,2,1] -- returns: [[1,2,3,2],[1]]
```

Step by step `groupBy`:

1. compares 1 with 2. 1 < 2, thus both numbers go into the same group. Groups: `[[1,2]]`
2. compares 1 with 3. 1 < 3, thus 3 goes into the old group. Groups: `[[1,2,3]]`
3. compares 1 with 2. 1 < 2, thus 2 goes into the old group. Groups: `[[1,2,3,2]]`
4. compares 1 with 1. 1 ≮ 1, thus the new group is formed, and 1 goes as its first element. Groups: `[[1,2,3,2],[1]]`

**Exercise:** To understand how `groupBy` works, try to figure out how the following expressions return their results with pen and paper:

```
groupBy (\x y -> x < y) [1,2,3,4,5,4,3,2,1] -- [[1,2,3,4,5,4,3,2],[1]]
groupBy (\x y -> x < y) [1,3,5,2,1] -- [[1,3,5,2],[1]]
groupBy (\x y -> x <= y) [3,5,3,2,1,0,1,0] -- [[3,5,3],[2],[1],[0,1,0]]
groupBy (\x y -> x <= y) [1,2,3,2,1] -- [[1,2,3,2,1]]
```

Again, the key to understand behavior of `groupBy` is to remember, that at each step it compares the **first** element of the current group with a consecutive element of the list. The moment predicate returns `False`, the new group is formed, and the process continues.

To understand *why* `groupBy` behaves that way, inspect its [source](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.7.0.2/docs/src/Data-List.html#groupBy):

```
groupBy                 :: (a -> a -> Bool) -> [a] -> [[a]]
groupBy _  []           =  []
groupBy eq (x:xs)       =  (x:ys) : groupBy eq zs
                           where (ys,zs) = span (eq x) xs
```

The key here is the use of [`span`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.7.0.2/docs/Data-List.html#v:span) function: `span (1<) [2,3,2,1]` returns `([2,3,2],[1])`. `span (eq x) xs` in the above code puts all elemets of `xs` that match `(eq x)` into the first part of a pair, and te rest of `xs` into the second. `(x:ys)` then joins `x` with the first part of a pair, while `groupBy` is recursively invoked on the rest of `xs` (which is `zs`). That's why `groupBy` works this strange way.